# Переделать функцию с С++ на C#

Tags: c#, c++

Есть функция подсчета Crc8, которая написана на C++ и эту функцию мне нужно перенести на C#

Вот сама функция:

```
uint8_t Crc8(unsigned char *pcBlock, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned char crc = 0xFF;
    unsigned int i;

    while (len--)
    {
        crc ^= *pcBlock++;

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x9B : crc << 1;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Начал я писать на С# и столкнулся с проблемой:

```
unsafe char Crc8(char* pcBlock, uint len)
{
    ushort crc = 0xFF;
    ushort i;

    while(Convert.ToBoolean(len))
    {
        crc ^= *pcBlock;

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x9B : crc << 1;
    }
}
```

Он не понимает строку:

```
crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x9B : crc << 1;
```

Пишет ошибку:

**Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "bool"**

Я пытался переконвертировать, но не получилось

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79836/discussion-on-question-by-razorqhex------c).

Comment: `char` в C++ имеет размер один байт. `char` в C# имеет размер два байта. В общем, всё нужно переписывать полностью.

Answer (score 5):

Ну всё верно, первый операнд тернарного оператора должен иметь тип `bool`, у вас же там число, надо писать явно `(crc & 0x80) != 0`

Но вообще тут куча проблем. На самом деле вам необходимо разобраться как работает этот алгоритм и переписать его в безопасном стиле, без использования указателей.

Answer (score -4):

вместо crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x9B : crc << 1;

```
if(crc & 0x80){
crc = ((crc << 1) ^ 0x9B);
}else
{
crc << 1;
}
```

я если что в c# нуб полный, но вроде так дожно прокатить

Comment: тип bool, ну в c++ так.

Comment: А то что этот код не скомпилируется вас не беспокоит?

Comment: Если смотреть условие, то ошибка будет такой же